# Check if next value is equal o current value in python loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops

I am looping through a file and I want to check if the next coming object is equal to current object. Both the objects have a attribute name like Obj.name

Here is some simplified example:

The file contains:

```
Oba_A
Obj_B
Obj_C
Obj_D
```

I am looping through them like:

```
for obj in open("file.txt"):
    check if Obj_A.name==Obj_B.name, if not:
        if Obj_B.name==Obj_C.name
```

I am a biologist learning programming. I hope I get enough encouragement here.

Comment: Is this the content of the file? Where are the objects? These are just **different** strings. Posting expected input and output can help us help you.

Comment: it depends what is really on each line in your file and what your end use of checking the objects is.

Comment: I am Reading a file and creating objects that I have not shown here.

Comment: Rather than check the next, check the *previous* value. It is much easier to remember what has already passed than to peek at the next value to be read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overlooking the issue of how you're getting objects from a text file, your basic answer could look something like this:

```
last_value = None
for obj in collection:
    if obj.name == last_value:
        # do something
    else:
        # do something different
    last_value = obj.name
```

**Update**:
If you want to *act* on the first object based on a match with the next object, you could store a reference to previous object instead of just the name, ex:

```
prev_obj = None
for obj in collection:
    if obj.name == prev_obj.name:
        # do something with prev_obj
    else:
        # do something different
    prev_obj = obj
```

Or, if it truly helps to think of these as "current" and "next":

```
cur_obj = None
for next_obj in collection:
    if next_obj.name == cur_obj.name:
        # do something with cur_obj
    else:
        # do something different
    cur_obj = next_obj
```

But notice that all I've done is changed the naming. The procedure is still the same.

**Additional Update:**
The first time through the loop, prev_obj is None, so it won't have a name attribute. Trap that case by updating this to:

```
prev_obj = None
for obj in collection:
    if prev_obj is not None and obj.name == prev_obj.name:
        # do something with prev_obj
    else:
        # do something different
    prev_obj = obj
```

Comment: Can we do similar but compare next value to current value instead of current value to previous value ? Like can we make last_value as initial value and compare against next value ?

Comment: I've updated the answer to act on the previous object instead of the next object. Logically, there is no difference in how you compare any two adjacent items in a sequence... but literally "looking ahead" in a collection is going to increase your code complexity and could significantly degrade your performance because you'll be accessing collection members two different ways. It's not impossible, but if you're just starting out, I'd encourage you to embrace the "right" way first.

Answer (score 2):

Keep track of last object we saw and compare to the current object:

```
objects = ([....])
prev = objects[0]
for obj in objects[1:]:
   if prev.name == obj.name:
       # do whatever
   else:
       # do something else
   prev = obj # update prev to current obj
```

If objects is some kind of iterator or indeed a file object use `prev = next(objects)` to start then just loop over the remaining objects.

On a side note use `with` to open your files as it closes them automatically:

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
   prev = next(f)
   for obj in f:
       # create objects
       if prev.name == obj.name:
            # do whatever
      else:
           # do something else
      prev = obj
```

Comment: Your use of the name `start` is confusing. Why not name it `previous` or `preceding`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, this tests all consecutive elements

Comment: @MartijnPieters, well it is the starting object so calling it previous would not be exactly correct either. either way the code does what the OP wants and does it efficiently

Comment: Only before the first iteration is it the starting object, thereafter it is the preceding or previous object you handled in the loop.

Comment: @MartijnPieters,  changed just for you

Comment: You'd want to iterate over `objects[1:]` perhaps? Otherwise `objects[0]` is going to be compared *again*, with itself.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, true, originally I used an iterator.

Comment: Which is probably a fine approach, seeing as the OP has a file to read.