# How do I sum consecutive items of a list when i'm using another parameter to decide it

Tags: python, list

I'm doing a problem right now and I'm kinda stuck. I have 2 lists, "sells" and "date". These sells are about several products, and I want to sum all the sells that are from the same month.

Let's say I have

```
sells = [25, 30, 1, 5, 15, 12]
date = [July 18, July 18, August 18, September 18, September 18, September 18]
```

Right now I'm trying to solve it like this:

```
last = None
sell = []
for s, d in zip(sells, date):
    if d == last
    sell.append(sum(s)
```

I'm kinda following the explanation i read over here: [Check if next value is equal o current value in python loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28258278/check-if-next-value-is-equal-o-current-value-in-python-loop) but I get no output at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "_I get no output at all_" There is nothing in the code which should output anything.

Comment: There are syntax errors in your code. Intendation after d==last is wrong and a : is missing and there is a missing ) at the end. And there is no output eg print. So what output you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` with `zip`:

```
from itertools import groupby 
sells = [25, 30, 1, 5, 15, 12]
date = ['July 18', 'July 18', 'August 18', 'September 18', 'September 18', 'September 18']
new_results = groupby(sorted(zip(date, sells), key=lambda x:x[0]), key=lambda x:x[0])
final_data = {a:sum(b for _, b in c) for a, c in new_results}
```

Output:

```
{'August 18': 1, 'July 18': 55, 'September 18': 32}
```

Comment: Thank you! That was really helpful. Tho, the Dictionary I get is alphabetically sorted and I miss the initial order.